# How to Replace image in CSS background using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to replace a CSS background image url of div using jQuery.

```
.file-wrapper {
        background: url("SiteRef_getPicture?PictureName=Site/icnUpload.png") no-repeat 7px center;
        width: 86px;
        height: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

I tried to do the following with no success:

```
$fileWrapperDiv.css("background", "url('SiteRef_getPicture?PictureName=Site/loader.png')", "no-repeat", "7px", "center");
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what that $fileWrapperDiv ? And use http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) documentation

```
$('div.file-wrapper').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
```

Commented by [Lasar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9438/lasar)

Your original CSS uses `background:`, which translates to `background-image`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`, etc. So when you override just `background-image`, the other settings will remain intact.

Comment: Shouldn't "background" work too, as you can specify a background image using only "background" in css?

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't I specify the rest of parameters 'no-repeat', etc ?

Comment: A little explanation as to why he only needs to replace the image would help, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Your original CSS uses "background:", which translates to "background-image", "background-position", "background-repeat", etc. So when you override just "background-image", the other settings will remain intact.

Comment: @Lasar added your comment in answer :)

Comment: Rory, this is a file upload "button" with "upload arrow" icon on the right side. The idea is to replace the upload arrow with progress loader while upload is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

The value in the `.css()` call must be a single string, just like the value in the CSS:

```
$fileWrapperDiv.css("background", "url('SiteRef_getPicture?PictureName=Site/loader.png') no-repeat 7px center");
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are there commas separating the CSS values? Shouldn't the CSS string reflect the actual, expected CSS?